# Why isn't my function trigger working?

Tags: jquery, function, click

**UPDATE:**
When you click on **.more** in my <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/a05vhgLn/9/)</kbd> the container re-sizes to fit window.

I need that same container to re-size when clicking **#trigger**, not **.more**.

```
var isFullscreen = false;

$('.more').click(function(f) {
    $('#trigger').click();
    f.isFullscreen = (f.isFullscreen === false) ? true : false;
    var d = {};
    var speed = 900;
    if (!isFullscreen) { // MAXIMIZATION
        d.width = $(window).width();
        d.height = $(window).height();
        isFullscreen = true;
    } else { // MINIMIZATION            
        d.width = "50px";
        d.height = "50px";
        isFullscreen = false;
    }

    $(this).animate(d, speed)
});
```

Here's my <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/a05vhgLn/9/)</kbd>

Comment: what are you expecting with `$('#trigger').click()`

Comment: What exactly is not working, do you get any error-message?

Comment: try `$('#trigger')[0].click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

`$('#trigger')[0].click();`

or

`$('#trigger').get(0).click();`

**Update** : Trigger the click event of `.more`

```
$('#trigger').click(function(){
    $('.more').click();
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a05vhgLn/13/)

Comment: @Alin, There is no event handler with `<div id="trigger">click</div>` what do you expect? Your problem statement is not clear.

Comment: @Satpal sorry about that, I want the .more to resize to fit window (see the code) when clicking #trigger

Comment: @karan3112 the alert is working but i need my .more to resize to fit window when clicking on #trigger.

Comment: @Alin Kindly edit your question. The question you have asked and the functionality you want is different and confusing. You will have attach a event handler with the `#trigger`.

Comment: @karan3112 sorry for the confusion, i made an update to my question, it clearer now. Sorry again

Comment: Still not sure but is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/a05vhgLn/11/

Comment: @karan3112 That's it :) Update your answer to vote it :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $("#trigger").trigger("click");

 $("#yourid").trigger("click");
```